# Create single onComplete for dynamic list of Completables

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using [this](https://github.com/kunny/RxFirebase) library for wrapping Firebase transactions with RxJava. I'm new to RxJava, so this is mainly a question regarding how to use it.

**Scenario**: There is a many-to-many relationship between `Person`s and `Label`s. A `Person` can have multiple `Label`s, and a `Label` can be given to many `Person`s. When a `Person` is created, I must:

- add them to the list of `Person`s
- update each `Label` given to them to allow for querying all `Persons` that belong to a specific label

I have a list of `Label`s I want to write to my Firebase database.

```
List<Label> labels; // Let's assume it's been instantiated and added to
```

I want to write each of these to the DB:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference peopleRef = database.getReference().child("people");
DatabaseReference labelsRef = database.getReference().child("labels");
int newPersonId = peopleRef.push().getKey();
```

I can do this easily if I don't care about whether the calls are successful.

```
// Let's assume I already saved the Person to the DB
for (Label label : labels){
    // For each label, index the Person saved (Looks like 'personId: true')
    labelsRef.child(label).child(newPersonId).setValue(true);
}
```

But what if I *do* care about the result? If I want to react to all `Label`s being updated (like navigate away from the current `Activity`), I need to know if they've all been updated successfully.

RxFirebase is implemented such that setting a value in the DB returns a `Completable`. I essentially want to zip together `n` number of Completables and do something only when they succeed or fail.

So far, I can do this if I only want to update one `Label`, but I want to update `n` `Label`s.

**The following code snippet chains 2 Completables together, but only saves 1 Label**

```
        RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(peopleRef.child(newPersonId), person)  // Save the Person 
 .andThen(RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(labelsRef.child(label).child(newPersonId), true)) // I can index 1 Label, and this returns a Completable
```

How would I do this? If you know Firebase well enough, is this even the right way to be saving a List of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your main question correctly, you have a collection of `Completable` and you need to subscribe to them as one.

The way to solve this is using the `Completable.concat` or `Completable.merge` operators.

> Completable.**concat**: Returns a Completable which completes only when all sources complete, one after another.
>
> Completable.**merge**: Returns a Completable instance that subscribes to all sources at once and completes only when all source Completables complete or one of them emits an error.

Example:

```
List<Completable> tasks;  // initialized elsewhere

Completable
    .concat(tasks)
    .subscribe(
        () -> Log.d(TAG, "All successful"),
        throwable -> Log.w(TAG, "One or more failed"))
```

About your second question, I don't know Firebase well enough.

**Update**: to obtain the `List<Completable>` you can do something similar to this:

```
List<Completable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for ( ... ) {
    tasks.add(RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(peopleRef.child(newPersonId), person));
}
Completable.concat(tasks).etc
```

Comment: This is great, and definitely better then using `andThen()` which I used in my question. I guess my only problem is that while this works for a series of single `Completable`s, what do you think is the best way to take that forEach loop in my question, turn each of those iterations into a `Completable` (since that's what each iteration returns), and then `concat()` them together?

Comment: I suppose I could have some method that returns a `Completable` and just call that for each `Label` that I need to update in the DB. I could make a `List` of those, and then `concat` them together. I'll give that a shot (unless you have a better way) and give the ol' green check a click if it all works.

Comment: @Brandon what does the following line return? `labelsRef.child(label).child(newPersonId).setValue(true);`.  If it returns a `Completable`, then put them in a `List` before using `concat`.

Comment: the one we're concerned with is this:

`RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(peopleRef.child(newPersonId), person)`

which returns a Completable. I want to basically `concat` a dynamic amount of these together.

Comment: @Brandon aah ok! I updated the answer with an example of this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this makes perfect sense and I'm a little embarrassed I didn't figure it out :( Maybe I'm still a bit intimidated by RxJava, haha. I'll update this as accepted later.